# Have previously set zsh as default, then uninstalled it, I now cannot use the bash in Visual Studio

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

terminal.integrated.shell.linux had "usr/bin/zsh" value. But as i have uninstalled it terminal didnt open

Then i changed some values
For, terminal.integrated.shell.linux, "bash"
For, terminal.integrated.shell.osx, "bash" too
And, terminal.external.linuxExec, "x-terminal-emulator"

It works now. I am able to use bash shell in visual code studio

Thanks everyone for helping

[image: This is visual code screenshot]

Comment: Your description is really not clear. From what I understand, you installed Zsh then uninstalled it, now you are trying to use Zsh in a terminal inside Visual Studio, but it's not working. ...But that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does this page help? [Visual Studio Code - Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Comment: Sir, actually when I installed zsh, i started using zsh terminal and even set it as default or something. Now that i have uninstalled zsh the visual studio settings still has zsh file's path but I want to use the basic terminal, the bash in visual studio

Comment: Set it to `/bin/bash` then.

Comment: @SachinKanthariya please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a wrong path configured on you editors *(or its related terminal plugins)*, anyway i'll advise checking/updating your default shell provider too.

To check/update you shell provider config you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config sh` to list and change default between installed shell interpreters *(ash/dash, zsh, fish, bash...)*.

Also you can directly set it to *bash* using `sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/sh sh /bin/bash 100`.

Then you should check on your editor's config and also the plugin(s) you are using to launch/open the terminal *(atom-terminal, terminal-plus, etc.)*.

- You should use `/bin/bash` where *shell interpreter* path is required.
- Use `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` or `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator` where the path of the *terminal emulator app* is required.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think they just need to set the path to `/bin/bash` inside the application - they don't need to do anything with `update-alternatives` as far as we can tell from the question. I would suggest editing your answer to emphasise the key point, something like "in the screenshot, where `/usr/bin/zsh` appears, you should replace it with `/bin/bash`". That's my interpretation, and I would rather upvote your answer than post another one since you seem more or less on track

Comment: I think you're right, answer updated.

Comment: In no way, thanks to your note I have been able to improve my answer ;)

Comment: For me, I had to add the following to my settings.json: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem recently. The easiest solution I can suggest you is to add this line in the settings.json file of Visual Studio Code. The recent version of Code lets you edit the settings.json via a GUI. Switch it to the JSON view mode. You can find that toggle button at the top right corner.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "bash"
```

And, you're done. Run the terminal. Bash should boost up.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Preferences > Settings or simply use `Ctrl+,`
- Search for `Terminal › Integrated › Shell: Linux`
- Click on `Edit in settings.json`
- Finally add this line `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux" : "/bin/bash"` and restart your application.